# Divide to two parts, not necessarily equal

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a paper about a geometric algorithm where one of the main operations is dividing a rectangles to two smaller rectangles. It is important that there are two pieces, and that the pieces don't have to be equal. I am looking for a single verb  that I can use in this context.

There are many English words that are specific to the number 2, for example "couple" (a group of 2), "half" (one of 2 equal parts), "both", etc. So, I thought there may be a word specific for dividing to two parts

I thought of *bisecting*, but according to [Meriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bisect) it means "two equal parts".

*Bipartite* seems like a good candidate, but according to [Meriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bipartite) it is an adjective, and I need a verb.

I asked in [ell](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11054/what-is-the-word-for-dividing-into-two-unequal-parts) and got many answers (*splitting*, *cleaving*, *dividing*, *separating*, *breaking*), but none of these imply that there are exactly 2 pieces.

EDIT: In the future I may change the algorithm to cut into 3 parts, so, it could be good to have a verb that can be naturally modified to indicate 3 parts.

Comment: As the context is geometric algorithms, try [math.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dichotomize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomize) means to specifically divide into two parts, with no inference about relative size of sub-groups. It has wide usage, especially in [statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16565/what-is-the-effect-of-dichotomising-variables) and [maths](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dichotomy_method). There is a famous paradox, called the [dichotomy paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox), which is pictorially described by drawing a rectangle and dividing it in two repeatedly.

Comment: Good point. *v. dichotomize* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dichotomize However, in general English, the more common implication is a difference of character/ classification, not parts of the same kind.

Comment: This also looks like a good option. There is also "trichotomize" which means dividing to three parts (if ever I need to change my algorithm from 2 to 3 parts)

Comment: What is the original meaning of "chotomize"?

Comment: [Dichotomy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dichotomy&searchmode=none) comes from the Greek dicha (meaning two) and temnein (to cut)

Answer (score 2):

**Bifurcation** may be one possible answer. To divide into two.

But it has two meanings, it may be *two parts* or *Y shaped*.

Refer [Bifurcation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bifurcation)

Comment: Rather, *bifurcate*, as the OP needs a *verb*. And no, not two meanings -- it just means to divide into two (at a particular point) -- the result can be two separate pieces or two branches still connected at the point of bifurcation ('Y'-shaped).

Comment: @Kris: Ok. According to the context, bifurcate may not be the word you are looking for. But, its a nice word though :D

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good option. The "bi" prefix emphasizes that there are two parts. And there is an additional benefit: if I ever need to change my algorithm to cut into three parts, I can use "trifurcate": http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trifurcate

Comment: Yes, but I rejected *bifurcate* in my search because *bifurcate* is about a single  flow **branching** into two separate streams. A single trunk splitting into two branches or a river splitting into to streams.  Objects that are bifurcated form a *Y*.  It's not about cutting one object into two separate objects.

Comment: @Jim now that I think of it, probably the "furc" syllable means something like "fork", so "bifurcate" is literally: create two forks/branches.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Not probably, it is really related to *fork*. Yet, it does not tell whether the result is two separate parts or a 'Y': http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bifurcate

Answer (score 2):

Pick the word that sounds best for you and add a disclaimer which explains its meaning in the context of your paper.
Most of the terms we use today are born that way.

The word doesn't have to be made up. Many science terms also have (different) everyday meanings.

Comment: What, like hemidisecticate?

Comment: The word doesn't have to be made up. Many science terms also have (different) everyday meanings.

Comment: @long hemidisecticate has one great advantage: it currently has no results in Google, so if I use it, my paper may have the privilege of being the only result for this word (except this StackExchange page, of course)

Answer (score 1):

It's marked obscure, but there is:

> [***discide***](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=discide&use1913=on) *: to divide; to cleave in two*

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discide), on the other hand, says “(obsolete) To cut apart; to cut into pieces” which doesn't limit the number of pieces to two.

Comment: yep, take it or leave it